# Classify command option question

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm using Classify to predict who is going to win a battle based on their strength. The input is something like {{"Name 1", Strength1},{"Name 2", Strength2},{"Name 3", Strength3},{"Name 4", Strength4} -> "Name Winner"} where "Name Winner" depends on who won. In this case the winner could be "Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3" or "Name 4". I have up to 20 names, so there may be 20 classes.

Is there is a option to make Classify understand that if the input is {{"Name 1", Strength1},{"Name 2", Strength2},{"Name 3", Strength3},{"Name 4", Strength4} -> "Name Winner" } the only possible winners are "Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3" or "Name 4", in other words, is not possible for "Name 5" or "Name 17" to be a possible output.

Comment: perhaps redefine your _classes_ to include possible winners, (e.g., `{"name winner", {"Name 1", "Name2", "Name3","Name 4"} }` for your example input), so that you can use the `UtilityFunction` to penalize mismatch of the actual and predicted values of  both class components?